# Is there a setup to add slash in the end of URL in CRA?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

After i install CRA from `npx create-react-app app-name` and then run `yarn start` it will be start the development server in `http://localhost:9000` by default.

The problem is, when i copy the url from browser address bar to my CORS middleware in the backend, the url showing `http://localhost:9000/`. This is will throw error `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` not allowed because slash in the end of url.

I want to change the url that showing on terminal after start CRA development server with slash in the end of url (`http://localhost:9000/`), how its possible? IMHO, slash in the end of url make url prettier hehe. That's why i want to add it beside of CORS problem.

**Thank you!**

Comment: have you considered using cors whitelisting to remove the error with Access-Control? I'm guessing that's the problem. But on the other hand, you cannot use `https` on localhost, it's not feasible.  Try using 'localhost:9000' on your core middleware whitelist

Comment: Sorry there's typo, I mean `https`. Yes i've used cors whitelisting to `https://localhost:9000/` the url I copied from address bar. But it will produce error because my dev server serving `https://localhost:9000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no absolute rule for this. A trailing slash is optional. However general theory is to avoid trailing slash.

[Here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser) you can read more about this. Below is a snippet from the link provided.

> You need to look at the HTTP request the browser makes to the server.
>   The URL displayed in the "status bar of the browser", or even the URL
>   in the address bar could be different - more user friendly. **Google
>   Chrome does not append the trailing slash in the status bar, although
>   the slash is present in the request.**

As per one of the post of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization), trailing slash indicates directory paths.

> Adding a trailing "/" to a non-empty path. Directories (folders) are indicated with a trailing slash and should be included in URIs.

As you already understand, URL `http:localhost:9000` is not same as `http://localhost:9000/`. They are different URLs and that is the reason CORS does not work. CORS URL should be domains and not specific URLs. In your case, your domain is `http://localhost:9000` and not `http://localhost:9000/`. So I would truly avoid adding `http://localhost:9000/` to CORS settings.

In my personal opinion, I would be sticking to the default behavior of browser and common notion in which URLs are perceived by most users until I have strong reason to change them. And for me, URL without additional slashes are more pretty :)

Comment: Ahh i see, thanks for the insight! I need to learn about URL, CORS and HTTP more maybe. In second thought, you we're right, URL without additional slashes more pretty. Thank you so much!